# AspNetCore._Areas_Customer_Views_Home_Details.<ExecuteAsync>b__15_0() in Details.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a project with **.Net 6** and JetBrains Rider.

i've added my product to main home page:
here is the code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Book.Models.Product>

<div class="row pb-3">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="product-card text-center">
                <img src="@product.ImageUrl" alt="@product.Title" class="card-img-top"/>
                <div class="card-body p-3">
                    <h5 class="product-title mb-0">@product.Title</h5>
                    <p class="product-author mb-0">by <b>@product.Author</b></p>
                    <p class="product-price mb-2">@product.Price.ToString("c")</p>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-productId="@product.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

each product has a Details button which suppose to go to Deatil page
here is the code for datails page:

````
@model Book.Models.ShoppingCart

<form method="post">
        <div class="card  container pt-4">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light ml-0  row ">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="text-white-50">@Model.Product.Title</h1>
                    <p class="text-warning">by @Model.Product.Author</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-end pt-4">
                    <span class="badge bg-info pt-2" style="height:30px;">@Model.Product.CoverType.Name</span>
                    <span class="badge bg-warning pt-2" style="height:30px;">@Model.Product.Category.Name</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body row container">
                <div class="container rounded p-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8 col-lg-8">

                            <div class="row pl-2">
                                <h5 class="text-muted">ISBN : @Model.Product.ISBN</h5>
                            </div>
                         
                            <div class="row text-center pl-2">
                                <div class="p-1 col-2 bg-secondary border-bottom">
                                    <div>Quantity</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row text-center pl-2" style="color:maroon; font-weight:bold">
                                <div class="p-1 col-2 bg-secondary">
                                    <div>Price</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="p-1 col-2 bg-secondary">
                                    <div>@Model.Product.Price.ToString("c")</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pl-2">
                                <p class="text-secondary">@Html.Raw(Model.Product.Description)</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pl-2">
                                <div class="col-2 text-primary"><h4>Count</h4></div>
                                <div class="col-10"><input asp-for="Count" class="form-control"  /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 offset-lg-1 text-center">
                            <img src="@Model.Product.ImageUrl" width="100%" class="rounded" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <a class="btn btn-success form-control " style="height:50px;" asp-action="Index">Back to Home</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <button type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary form-control" style="height:50px;">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>```

but when i click on details button, it throws this Error:
[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MTT3.png)

let me show you the ShoppingCart model in case problem is from there:
````

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Book.Models;

public class ShoppingCart
{
public Product Product { get; set; }

```
[Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value between 1 and 1000")]
public int Count { get; set; }
```

}

```
what would be the cause of this error ?



i suspect its something about my ShoppingCart model
```

Comment: The error indicates  Product.Title property is null,you have to show your codes in Details action to let us know how you pulled the data